# Can't write to Flash drive anymore, only reformatting helps

Tags: ubuntu, usb-flash-drive

On Ubuntu 10.04, I often cannot write to my Kingston flash drive formatted as FAT32. The only thing that helps is reformatting the thing.

I do not know why this happens – can it be prevented?

I tried `chmod -Rf 777` on the device, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: I think you're approaching the problem from the wrong side. What kind of flash drive is it? Where are you mounting it? How is it partitioned? Why do you think `chmod`ding it would help?

Comment: it is a kingston with fat32 and one partition. after running chmod i still could not copy files to the flashdrive. I inserted into the usb port of my pc box. i am running ubuntu 10.4.

Comment: And when you re-format it, it works again (at least for a certain amount of time)?

Comment: yes then all is ok again but then i have to backup each time. i just thought there would be a command to force write permissions. what is the ubuntu command for re-format please?

Comment: Something along `mkfs.vfat -F 32 -n "newname" /dev/<your-usb-device>`. But I'd say the most important problem is trying to find out why it doesn't work after some time.